# What is the token introspection path for AWS Cognito

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, vert.x

We are using vertx oauth2 components to implement login with cognito using oauth2 authorization code grant. We could implement the scenario using existing APIs. But vertx expect token introspect path in it's oauth2 config. Otherwise there is no way to ask from cognito whether the provided token to the resource server is correct or not. Anyway we could not find any information on what is the token instrospect context path on cognito documentation.

```
OAuth2ClientOptions oAuth2ClientOptions = new OAuth2ClientOptions()
                .setClientID("***************************")
                .setIntrospectionPath("") //what should goes here
                .setClientSecret("********************")
                .setSite("*****************")
                .setTokenPath("/oauth2/token")
                .setAuthorizationPath("/oauth2/authorize")
                .setFlow(OAuth2FlowType.AUTH_CODE)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no introspection endpoint for AWS Cognito so you have to use a different approach:

- Download token signing keys from the JWKS endpoint
- Use a library to verify the token signature

If it helps, here is some [nodejs code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.serverless/blob/master/src/plumbing-oauth/src/oauth/oauthAuthenticator.ts) that validates Cognito tokens.

I've not used vertx but it seems to support [JWT Validation](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-auth-jwt/js/#_validating_tokens). Usually this involves including the JWKS or metadata URL in an Options object.

Comment: Token introspection happen inside vertx framework. The only thing I can do from my side is to provide the introspection path. If we go with your solution, then we have to check if overridden possible on vertx ouath2 implementation or completely abandoned vertx.isn't it?

Comment: Introspection will not work with Cognito unfortunately (I always use introspection when it is supported). So OPTION 1 is to find a way to do it with vertx. OPTION 2 is to use a different library. When I do Java based OAuth I always use the excellent [Nimbusds libraries](https://connect2id.com/products/nimbus-jose-jwt/examples/validating-jwt-access-tokens) which come with really good docs.

Comment: The choice of security library can be important, as you are finding. The [certified libraries page](https://openid.net/developers/certified/) is where I usually start. The best libraries enable you to work around vendor limitations.

Comment: So if an access token that is still valid has been revoked as a result of an app client being deleted from Cognito, does that mean the JWK will also be removed from Cognito effective immediately such that the next validation will fail?

Comment: Nope - the JWK is used for many tokens for many apps. Bearer tokens remain valid until their expiry. The simple option is to keep tokens short lived (~60 minutes), so that revocation is something you don't bother coding. If you go down other roads you are likely to be disappointed and find the tech doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Guys, just to clarify I'm trying to use Cognito with Token Introspection with Spring Security and Nimbus can't decode the token because the Cognito token doesn't have the active parameter. So this is not possible with Cognito?

Comment: That's right - Cognito does not have an introspection endpoint - you will need to use in memory token validation of Cognito JWTs. Here is [some Nimbusds code](https://github.com/gary-archer/authguidance.apisample.javaspringboot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/mycompany/sample/plumbing/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java) if it helps, though you may be able to do this with less code with Spring Security.